# XmlNode.AppenChild method is too slow

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, appendchild

I have a large xml file, there's about 500 child nodes in the root node.
When I use AppendChild method to append a new node, this method last a very long time, about several minutes. But, after the first append completed, appending more nodes is very fast. I also tried Prepend and InsertAfter method, neither works. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using XmlWriter class instead:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("..."))
{
 writer.WriteElementString(...);
}
```

It will not load everything to memory, therefore execution should be faster.